# Operators not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery

ok i did according to your suggestion but somewhat it looks amatuerish ha.. cos it repeats the same thing for each percentage group: css and message. I am wondering if there is another way to change it? If not, i am ok with this..

if (69 < percentDiscount && percentDiscount < 101) {

```
        $(this).find("#percentoff").html('&gt; 70% off');
        $(this).find("#percentoff").addClass('badge70');
    }

    else if (49 < percentDiscount && percentDiscount < 70) {

        $(this).find("#percentoff").html('&gt; 50% off');
        $(this).find("#percentoff").addClass('badge50');
    }

    else if (29 < percentDiscount && percentDiscount < 50) {

        $(this).find("#percentoff").html('&gt; 30% off');
        $(this).find("#percentoff").addClass('badge30');
    }


    else if (19 < percentDiscount && percentDiscount < 30) {

        $(this).find("#percentoff").html('&gt; 20% off');
        $(this).find("#percentoff").addClass('badge30');
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're checking for a `percentDiscount` that's both higher than **both** numbers, so the in your second `if` check, there are no numbers left that are also *above* 69.  It should look like this instead (keeping your exclusion logic):

```
if (percentDiscount > 69 && percentDiscount < 101) {    
    $(this).find("#percentoff").html('&gt; 70% off');
    $(this).find("#percentoff").addClass('badge70');
}    
else if (percentDiscount > 49 && percentDiscount < 69) {    
    $(this).find("#percentoff").html('&gt; 50% off');
    $(this).find("#percentoff").addClass('badge50');
}    
else if (percentDiscount > 29 && percentDiscount < 49) {    
    $(this).find("#percentoff").html('&gt; 30% off');
    $(this).find("#percentoff").addClass('badge30');
}
```

Swap the terms so they're in the same order like I have above, I think you'll find it's *much* easier to read.  However, overall your terms exclude the `69`, and `49` points specifically, so I'd change your logic to this:

```
if (percentDiscount > 69) {    
    $(this).find("#percentoff").html('&gt; 70% off');
    $(this).find("#percentoff").addClass('badge70');
}    
else if (percentDiscount > 49) {    
    $(this).find("#percentoff").html('&gt; 50% off');
    $(this).find("#percentoff").addClass('badge50');
}    
else if (percentDiscount > 29) {    
    $(this).find("#percentoff").html('&gt; 30% off');
    $(this).find("#percentoff").addClass('badge30');
}
```

The first `if` grabs those above 69, the next those above, 49, etc...much simpler :)

Comment: Correction, she's checking if a number is lower than a variable and then if the variable is lower than a different number.  The second check makes the first check redundant.

Comment: @Andy - doh you're right, swapping the terms around makes that very had to read, fixing in the correction above

Comment: @Nick: yeah, threw me at first too -- I almost always write the variable first in these conditions.  +1

Comment: @Nick: That form is awkward to read. The canonical representation is all less-than signs, `min < x && x < max`, to mirror the standard mathematical notation, `min < x < max` (which some languages, e.g., Python, support directly).

Comment: @Marcelo - Depends on your point of view I suppose...in either case I think it's a moot point since it can be done much simpler overall :)

Comment: @Marcelo: I disagree, the `&&` in there separates it into two expressions.  IMO it makes more sense to have the variable you're testing come first in an expression, which is also how you would say it out loud - *"if percent discount is greater than 69 AND percent discount is less than 101"*.

Comment: @Andy: Actually, I read it as, "69 is less than percent discount is less than 101", which is how I learned to read it in school. Another helpful way to read it is, "Percent discount is between 69 and 101." Also, by standardising on `<` in most places, I find it much easier to scan my code, since I have one less symbol to recognise and interpret; whatever is on the left is always smaller.

Comment: @Marcelo: I meant reading the code aloud. I think it's fair to read and write it your way for languages which support it, but in JavaScript you must use the AND -- ignoring it is more likely to confuse people. Of course, that is just my opinion :-)

Comment: @Andy: That *is* how I read it aloud, and so far I've never had anyone complain or get confused. Each to his own, I guess.

Comment: @Andy, @Nick, @Marcelo, thank you very much and I edited my code above. I am still learning and hopefully I grow from learning from you all.

Answer (score 5):

You've got the > round the wrong way.  Let's look at the first one as an example:

```
if (percentDiscount > 69 && percentDiscount > 101)
```

(I reversed the first condition because I think it makes what's next more obvious.)

So percentDiscount has to be greater than 69 AND greater than 101.  You want

```
if (69 < percentDiscount && percentDiscount < 101)
```

This should do what you expect.

Comment: This won't do what's expected, since `49` and `69` percent won't hit any of these `if` cases :)

Comment: @nick, thank you for your help. I edited above. I am still figuring how to change the code so it doesn't need to rely on numbers to check. mm..

Answer (score 2):

In the first test, you are testing whether percentDiscount is greater than 69 *and* greater than 101. I think you meant this:

```
if (69 < percentDiscount && percentDiscount < 101) ...
```

The remaining tests have the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this line:

```
if (69 < percentDiscount && percentDiscount > 101) {
```

There are two problems here. First: you're doing the comparisons wrong. From this if statement, you're checking if `percentDiscount` is bigger than 69 and if it's bigger than 101. So, this will hold only if it's bigger than 101. What you probably wanted is this:

```
if (69 < percentDiscount && percentDiscount < 101) {
```

This can be written better as:

```
if (percentDiscount > 69 && percentDiscount < 101) {
```

But, there's still one problem. Operator precedence. The last example should be written as

```
if ( (percentDiscount > 69) && (percentDiscount < 101) ) {
```

to avoid ambiguities.

Comment: Operator precedence isn't a problem here, logical and/or have lower precedence than `<` and `>`.

Comment: @Andy: I'm aware of that, but it should be good practise to use parentheses because stuff like this isn't always obvious